# Creating Intellij Plugin, gradle cannot find org.jetbrains.intellij

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, intellij-14

I'm tryinging to create a plugin for intellij using gradle, I've followed jetbrains tutorial:
https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/tutorials/build_system/prerequisites.html

and I get the following error:

```
Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.intellij', version: '0.3.9'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.jetbrains.intellij:org.jetbrains.intellij.gradle.plugin:0.3.9')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
```

Taking a look at the gradle build file, there is the following lines:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.jetbrains.intellij' version '0.3.9'
}
```

How do I find out what version of org.jetbrains.intellij I do have?  How do I get 0.3.9?

My version of intellij is 2018.2.2 Community

Comment: This looks like a network problem. The version 0.3.9 is available in the plugins repository: https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.jetbrains.intellij

Comment: You are correct.  I needed to add my VM parameters to gradle because of my proxy.

Comment: Another scenario where this may happen is when trying to load the Gradle project from within IntelliJ. If that is the case it's worth checking the JVM being used by Gradle. Build,Execution,Deployment>Build Tools>Gradle and for your Gradle project, select the Gradle JVM required for your project. I had this problem with projects requiring SDK 11 but the Gradle JVM was set with SDK 8.